# Low-level TCP programming

Tags: sockets, tcp, low-level

I badly need some tools for low-level TCP socket programming (e.g., reception of SYN TCP packets, working with TCP connection queue, etc.). Preferred PL: C/C++ or Ruby, preferred OS: Windows, but Linux is also suitable. Will be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

For C++  you can use :

[WinpCap](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/main.html)

And a port of this very same library exists for managed code:

[Pcap.net](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/)

with these libraries you can send and receive any type of packet. including SYN TCP.

Comment: Thanks, PCap is pretty helpful, but it's still just about packets. Anything about connections, like in TCPView?